# How to move objects with special conditions from old pdf to new pdf using iText?

Tags: java, object, itext

I want to write the JAVA program following :

1. reading pdf file
2. searching objects with special condition.
3. creating new pdf file with objects in second step

Where can I get the example or tips?

Comment: What are objects with special conditions? Marked objects? OCG layers? Annotations? Your question won't get an answer if you're not more specific.

Comment: I want to find string and image object of interest by program and copy it into new PDF.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question remains problematic. It reveals a lack of understanding of ISO-32000-1 (which is the PDF specification). Therefor it is very unlikely that you'll get an answer.

Comment: I want to do similar work in http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279, but output must be PDF. How to get the position of string and image object? I have to read PDF specification?

Comment: For example, attached source and output pdf https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5872993/from.pdf https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5872993/to.pdf

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I want make from.pdf into to.pdf. Can you give me a tips? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want something like the classes that are published here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/ However: you won't succeed if you don't know what a PDF looks like on the inside, so yes, you have to read the PDF specification.

Comment: Your question inspired me to make this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE If you watch it in HD, you will get an idea of what a PDF looks like on the inside. It should give you a grasp of what you're asking.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie How can I get toUnicodeCmap from pdf font dictionary using itext?

Comment: That's shown in the video, isn't it? Whatever you can do manually using RUPS, can be done programmatically using iText.

Comment: I saw the video, but I want do it programmatically. I want reverse mapping string to cmap(?) and write it other pdf like this cb.getInternalBuffer().append("<").append(ws).append(">").append(" Tj\n")

Comment: Nobody prevents you from doing it programmatically. If you don't succeed or if you have a question, feel free to post a question on SO, but don't hijack an existing question by another person.